# How to print/render nested objects properties using html in javaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, search

I am searching on nested objects. I want to render objects properties but every time i have to go in object like mobiles.apple.iphone12.properties. I have multiple mobiles in object if i do like that it will be very lengthy code. I just want to print in shorter way. Check out the JavaScript code below.

```js
let searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn')

let mobiles = {
    apple: {
        iphone13: {
            model: 'iphone 13',
            color: 'black',
            price: 1000,
            camera: 20,
            battery: 500,
        },
        iphone12: {
            model: 'iphone 12',
            color: 'red',
            price: 800,
            camera: 15,
            battery: 400,
            src: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhdp92UKK3NxwNfcIBlyZX8g26kEYBG3WNoQ&usqp=CAU"
        }
    },
    samsung: {
        s10: {
            model: 'Samsung S10',
            color: 'black',
            price: 500,
            camera: 10,
            battery: 600,
        },
        a10: {
            model: 'Samsung A10 ',
            color: 'blue',
            price: 300,
            camera: 20,
            battery: 150,
        }
    },
    moto: {
        motoz: {
            model: 'Moto Z',
            color: 'black',
            price: 500,
            camera: 10,
            battery: 300,
        },
        motoe4: {
            model: 'Moto E4',
            color: 'black',
            price: 200,
            camera: 10,
            battery: 300,
        }
    },

    techno: {
        camon18: {
            model: 'Camon 18',
            color: 'golden',
            price: 5000,
            camera: 10,
            battery: 300,
        },
        spark7: {
            model: 'Spark 7',
            color: 'sky blue',
            price: 2000,
            camera: 10,
            battery: 300,
        }
    }
}
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let brandName = document.getElementById('brand-name').value
    let modelName = document.getElementById('model-name').value

    if (mobiles[brandName] !== undefined) {
        if (mobiles[brandName][modelName] !== undefined) {
            console.log(mobiles[brandName][modelName])
        }

        else {
            console.log('This model is not available')
        }
    }
    else if (brandName == '' || modelName == '') {
        console.log('Brand name OR Model name is empty')
    }
    else {
        console.log('This model is not available')
    }
})

let card = `<div class="card">
    <img src="${mobiles.apple.iphone12.src}" style="width:100%">
    <h1> ${mobiles.apple.iphone12.model} </h1>
    <p class="price"> Rs: ${mobiles.apple.iphone12.price}</p>
    <p> Color: ${mobiles.apple.iphone12.color} </p>
    <p> Battery: ${mobiles.apple.iphone12.battery} </p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
</div>`
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += card
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 300px;
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
}

img {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.price {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.card button {
    border: none;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:active {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
    
    <input type="text" id="brand-name" placeholder="Enter Brand Name">
    <input type="text" id="model-name" placeholder="Enter Model Name">
    <button id="search-btn">Searh Phone</button>
    
    <div id="container">  </div>
```

Comment: so what are you trying to achieve? Create a card when someone searches and you find an entry in the object? In this case, why is the card created outside of the listener?

Comment: Improve your data modelling. Use arrays. Only reason your code needs to know the model name `iphone12`, is because you use it as a key in the apple object. Use an array so you can `.find()` and `.filter()`. That way you can use the same card for all phones, instead of a separately programmed card for each phone, without knowing all model names beforehand.

Comment: @ Cristian-Florin Calina, if i create card in the event listner then than ui will show at mouse click only.

Answer (score 1):

So from my understanding you are trying to create the initial displayed items.

You can have a generic function that generates the cards filtered or unfiltered.

```js
const generateCards = (brand = '', model = '') => {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    
    Object.entries(mobiles)
    .filter(([key]) => key.includes(brand))
    .forEach(([, mobile]) => {
        Object.entries(mobile)
        .filter(([key]) => key.includes(model))
        .forEach(([, model])=> {
            const card = document.createElement('div');
            card.classList.add('card');
            card.innerHTML = `${model.src ? ('<img src=' + model.src + '} style="width:100%">') : ''}
                <h1> ${model.model} </h1>
                <p class="price"> Rs: ${model.price}</p>
                <p> Color: ${model.color} </p>
                <p> Battery: ${model.battery} </p>
                <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>`;
            fragment.appendChild(card)
        })
    })

    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = fragment;
}
```

Then you can call `generateCards()` initially and it will generate all of the cards, and on the listeners for the brand and model you just call it with those values `generateCards(brand, model)`

Comment: I have rendered objects in cards using for in loop its more simpler and easier. Now i just want to do that if i click on search btn the model/phone, which is being searched, it's card should come on the top.

Comment: well this function would work to render the cards initially OR while being searched.  You can call it initially without any brand or model, and when the user selects a brand and a model and presses search, call it again with those parameters. It will update the cards shown to reflect only the searched ones. You should not have different logic for displaying initial cards vs filtered cards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, reading your question, that you want a user to search for a brand/model and get as output the device specs (if present).

If so, first thing you should do is to put the creation of the card inside your eventlistener definition, otherwise you won't be able to render any of them.

I made some changes in the snippet below; in this case you don't have to create `card` specifying model and brand in advance.

```js
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let brandName = document.getElementById('brand-name').value;
  let modelName = document.getElementById('model-name').value;

  if (!mobiles[brandName] || brandName == '') {
    console.log('Brand not available');
    return;
  }

  if (!mobiles[brandName][modelName] || modelName == '') {
    console.log('Model not available');
    return;
  }

  console.log(mobiles[brandName][modelName]);

  // Clear previous search
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = null;

  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += getMobileinfoHtmlElement(
    mobiles[brandName][modelName]
  );
});

function getMobileinfoHtmlElement(mobile) {
  return `<div class="card">
          <img src="${mobile.src}" style="width:100%">
          <h1> ${mobile.model} </h1>
          <p class="price"> Rs: ${mobile.price}</p>
          <p> Color: ${mobile.color} </p>
          <p> Battery: ${mobile.battery} </p>
          <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
      </div>`;
}
```

This code works if you are going to use nested objects. Speaking about best practice, arrays should be better; they have pre-built methods like `.filter()` or `.find()` that can be useful in this case.

Comment: What if he wants to filter only by brand? Or only by model?

Comment: From his source code I assumed both parameters were mandatory since he logs only when "model" and "brand" are both filled, that's why I kept using same logic here. Anyway, searching by brand/model should be possible still with this kind of logic (removing some if clauses and adding some code).
Of course, as I already said on my answer, best practices would say arrays are better at handling this kind of data! It depends on what are user purposes: practicing with nested objects in particular or not

Comment: his question was how to create the card elements without duplicating code, so I think he wanted to have multiple cards. But yea, arrays are better for this kind of tasks